# What is the correct action for this edit?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

The [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1668510) in question. Whats supposed to be done ?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd reject that. `@name` references *do not work* in posts, only in comments, and we only have the editor's word for it that he indeed once was called `braklet`. There is no point in the change, really.

Instead, the post should be edited to *remove* those references instead. It's a comment inside of the post, those should be removed (perhaps moved to a comment instead).

Comment: *moved to a comment* Can mods do that (such that its in OP's name) ?

Comment: @AshRj: Not certain; I suspect that converting an answer to a comment is a whole-post afair.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Pretty sure you are right, there. It's probably up to the OP to re-issue that @-comment.